# Raphael.js animate of image doesn't repaint in chrome

Tags: javascript, raphael

It seems to happen only when I try to animate an image on Chrome. All I want to do is make an image to move back an forth in Raphaël.js. I created a jsfiddle that illustrates the problem. I'm very sure that it used to work in Chrome since I use it to develop and it seems to be broken in later versions of Chrome. When I change the image to a rect for example it seems to render fine. When you resize the screen that contains the animation it repaints.

http://jsfiddle.net/k69yzz0o/1/

```
var moveForth = function () {
    useControl.animate({x : 38, y: 0}, 900, moveBack);
};

var moveBack = function () {
    useControl.animate({x : 0, y: 0}, 600, moveForth);
};

var R = Raphael("holder", 500, 500);
useControl = R.image("http://i.imgur.com/ta8zlD2.png", 0, 0, 189, 18);
moveForth();
```

It only happens in Chrome and I use latest Raphael.js 2.1.2.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: it worked for me in chrome. version: 37.0.2

Comment: My version is 38.0.2125.122 and I use osx, I asked a friend on windows, same issue with same Chrome version. Could you maybe update to latest version and confirm it's broken. I cannot find a way to install an older Chrome version.

Comment: Has the same problem for me in 38.0.2125.111 (Linux), works fine in Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there appears to be an issue with Chrome recognizing the rect as dirty, and refusing to repaint it.  You can see that it's working by mousing over the area.

I tried the same animation using a Transform rather than using the actual position.  Transforming an object evidently correctly tells modern Chrome to redraw that area.

Here it is working:

```
var moveForth = function () {
    useControl.animate({"transform":"T38,0"}, 900, ">", moveBack);
};

var moveBack = function () {
    useControl.animate({"transform":""}, 600, "<", moveForth);
};

var R = Raphael("holder", 500, 500);
useControl = R.image("http://i.imgur.com/ta8zlD2.png", 0, 0, 189, 18);
moveForth();
```

I also added some easing (`">"`) to give it a more natural bounce.